# New features' syntax in C++

Tags: c++

I'm a programmer who learned C++ when it was going through changes and managed to avoid STL. Instead I used MFC container classes and whatever container classes were available with the framework I might be using.

I also never really used smart pointers. 8)

So, I'm taking a look at the new features in C++ (with VS 2013)

The following compiles and works fine:

```
vector<string> names;
names.push_back("tom");
names.push_back("dick");
names.push_back("harry");
names.push_back("bob");
names.push_back("percy");
names.push_back("freddie");
names.push_back("sam");

for (auto name : names)
{
    cout << "Name: " << name << endl;
}
```

The following does not:

```
vector<unique_ptr<Thing>> things;
things.push_back(unique_ptr<Thing>(new Thing("tom", 23)));
things.push_back(unique_ptr<Thing>(new Thing("dick", 26)));
things.push_back(unique_ptr<Thing>(new Thing("harry", 33)));
things.push_back(unique_ptr<Thing>(new Thing("fred", 43)));
things.push_back(unique_ptr<Thing>(new Thing("bob", 53)));

for (auto thing : things)
{

}
```

I get the following error message:

```
1>c:\dev\src\samples\consoletest\consoletest\vectorstuff.cpp(34): error C2280: 'std::unique_ptr<Thing,std::default_delete<_Ty>>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &)' : attempting to reference a deleted function
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=Thing
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\memory(1486) : see declaration of 'std::unique_ptr<Thing,std::default_delete<_Ty>>::unique_ptr'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=Thing
1>          ]
```

So I tried standard iterators:

```
for (auto thing = things.begin(); thing != things.end(); ++thing)
{
    cout << "Name: " << (*thing)->getName() << " age: " << (*thing)->getAge() << endl;
}
```

which compiles fine, so why doesn't the for (auto thing : things) syntax work?

Here's my definition for Thing:

```
class Thing
{
public:
    Thing();
    Thing(const Thing& original);
    Thing(const std::string& name, int age);

    const std::string& getName() const { return name; }
    int getAge() const { return age; }

private:
    std::string name;
    int age;
};
```

and the code:

```
Thing::Thing() : name(""), age(21)
{
}

Thing::Thing(const Thing& original) : name(original.name), age(original.age)
{
}

Thing::Thing(const std::string& name, int age) : 
    name(name),
    age(age)
{
}
```

I added the default constructor and copy constructor but still get the deleted function.

Comment: "managed to avoid STL. Instead I used MFC container classes" - please don't. Just don't do that.

Comment: BTW, it doesn't work because `unique_ptr` cannot be copied.

Comment: It was a long time ago. I no longer use MFC.

Comment: `for (auto name : names)` is better as `for (const auto& name : names)` otherwise it copies the string

Comment: Hint: you'll have more problems that will stem from the fact that you have an `std::vector` of `std::unique_ptr` for the same reason mentioned in the answers (you can't copy a `unique_ptr`).

Comment: I would not put unique_ptrs into the vector at the first place. Most likely your contained objects (Things) are bound to the lifetime of the vector, so go ahead and insert them by value.

Comment: @Sambuca: it depends if OP has to keep reference to `Thing` elsewhere  (and modify the `vector<Thing>` and so invalidates the reference of `Thing`).

Comment: Ah, but then I should use shared_ptr if I'm referring to Thing elsewhere

Comment: @Sambuca: That's true for this simple example. If `Thing` were a base class, and you wanted to store objects of various derived types, then `unique_ptr<Thing>` would be a sensible thing to store.

Comment: @imekon shared ptr is for shared lifetime management, not shared references in general.  C++ smart pointers are about lifetime management.  Now a 3rd party ptr does generally imply the object outlives it, but that *can* be handled without it being smart.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`auto thing : things` copies by value, which is disabled for `unique_ptr`. Instead use:

```
auto &thing : things
```

The difference between this case and the iterator-based loop, is that in this case, `auto thing` is defined in accordance with `auto thing = *begin;` ([see here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) for more info).

However in the case where you write `auto thing = things.begin();`,  `thing` is actually an iterator, so everything is fine.

Answer (score 7):

`auto thing : things` means that the value of `thing` in each iteration is a *copy* of an element of `things`. If the type is not copyable (as `unique_ptr` isn't), then this won't work.

Instead, make `thing` a reference:

```
for (auto & thing : things)   // add "const" if appropriate
```

Answer (score 2):

In some cases (for example if `things` happens to be `vector<bool>`) `for (auto& thing : things)` won't compile. More general approach is to use

```
for (auto&& thing : things)
```

This is the syntax which will be implicitly used by [C++17 terse range-based for loops](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3994.htm) (`for (thing : things)`), so you can start getting used to it right now.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to using

```
for (auto & thing : things)
```

to access your objects instead of a copy, consider this:

```
things.push_back(unique_ptr<Thing>(new Thing("tom", 23)));
```

This creates a new `Thing` on the heap, and pushes a pointer to it into the vector `things`.
Why not simply store the `Thing` in `things` and let the vector handle all the memory for you?

```
things.push_back(Thing("tom", 23);
```

Comment: That's true, since I used unique_ptr, implying only one instance of a pointer to Thing. Usually, I need more than one reference, so I should use shared_ptr, which in the example above works fine without auto&